# How to show department_id, department_name and the head of the department?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

This is as far as i am getting, the output should be so that the head of that department is under the department_name in the same column

```
SELECT department_id, department_name
FROM (SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, 0 AS ent
      FROM departments d
UNION ALL
SELECT d.department_id, '--Department Head: '||e.last_name, 1 AS ent
FROM employees e INNER JOIN departments d ON e.manager_id = d.manager_id)
GROUP BY department_id, ent, department_name
ORDER BY department_id, ent, department_name;
```

I re wrote the query but still i don't know how to get the manager for each deartment...

```
10  Administration
20  Marketing
20  --Department Head: Fay
30  Purchasing
30  --Department Head: Baida
30  --Department Head: Colmenares
30  --Department Head: Himuro
30  --Department Head: Khoo
30  --Department Head: Tobias
40  Human Resources
50  Shipping
50  --Department Head: Atkinson
50  --Department Head: Bissot
50  --Department Head: Bull
```

```
Department_ID              Department_name

10                         Administration

10                         Manager: Neena

20                         Marketing

20                         Manager: Harstrein

30                         Purchasing

30                         Manager: Popp
```

Comment: Syntax error. (Missing `)`.)

Comment: maybe you can provide us a set of data of your table, would be nice for us to help you, just few rows will do

Comment: @Dean
I tried a deifferent query

SELECT department_id, department_name
FROM (SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, 0 AS ent
      FROM departments d
UNION ALL
SELECT d.department_id, e.last_name, 1 AS ent
FROM employees e INNER JOIN departments d ON e.manager_id = d.manager_id)
GROUP BY department_id, ent, department_name;


 and this is what i am getting
<pre>
10 Administration
20 Marketing
20 Fay
30 Purchasing
30 Baida
30 Colmenares
30 Himuro
30 Khoo
30 Tobias
40 Human Resources
</pre>

Comment: @Dean
I have no idea how to fix what i just wrote before...ehhh

Comment: The sql statement in your question has a syntax error, as jarlh suggested. That is probably the problem you are having, so please put the ")" where it is meant to be placed.

Comment: You have a "(" without a ")", get it?

Comment: @Webeng
Doesn't fix my problem because i think my query is wrong to begin with

Comment: In that case, correct your question with the ")" so that we can clearly see the problem, otherwise we can't be sure where you wanted to place the ")" in the first place...

Comment: Are you getting an Error when you run, or are you getting the wrong result?

Comment: @Webeng Runs fine just doesn't give me the manager for each department :/

Comment: Ok so in your answer, give us a screenshot of the result you are getting, and then show us what you want to get. This is very important because we need to know exactly what you want. Once you have done that, we will probably easily give you the solution.

Comment: @Asim Khan try the solution i gave and see isn't the result you want, i will try to change if there has not meet your requirement

Comment: @Webeng i provided a sample output of what i am getting ....

Comment: @Dean I tried but i don't want 3 columns i only want 2, and im still getting multiple rows :/

Comment: @Asim Khanok.. is that example data above is your expected result that you want? or can you provide us the expected result you need

Comment: Ok, and please also include an example of what you want. the above is what you are currently getting.

Comment: @Webeng
Okay so i want something like the table i added to my op

Comment: 1 more question to be ask. Isn't you have more than 1 employee's manager_id is bind to the same departments, if so there won't show the result that you need, or you have an identity to figure out which employee is the head

Comment: @Dean Not a clue as to how to identify who is the head...

Comment: please give me table structure of both tables